# How to bind data in XAML programmatically

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, avaloniaui

I am using roslynpad project for educational purposes.
It is based on avalon dock library which implements MVVM pattern which is new to me.
There are editors window's which can be docked. I want to add new window that could be docked also but it should be my custom window.
I see that dock manager binds to collection of OpenDocumentViewModel objects. OpenDocumentViewModel represents the model of the view as is understand.
Than there is a DocumentView class which describes a layout of the window.
Now there is a line in main window xaml file:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:OpenDocumentViewModel}">
        <roslynPad:DocumentView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

This line is responsible for connecting view model and document view, in other words says that for that DocumentView design should be attached to windows in OpenDocumentViewModel collection.

I want to insert my window with my own design. So for particular window i would like to write

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ui:OpenDocumentViewModel}">
        <MyCustomView />
    </DataTemplate>
```

But i don't know how to do that or maybe it is impossible?

Comment: You can put whatever you want in there essentially, it just needs to bind correctly to it's context and provide any mandatory elements https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-templating-overview

Comment: I recommend you have a look at the intro tutorials in the [Github repo](https://github.com/Dirkster99/AvalonDock)